# Can anybody help me to draw this image?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I am new to Tikz. If anybody knows how to draw tracing graph,it would be really helpful for me

[image]

Comment: To just draw the two curves and the axis see the `pdfplots` package. You can find example at http://pgfplots.sourceforge.net/gallery.html and https://texample.net/tikz/examples/pgfplots/

Comment: It's the `pgfplot` package…

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Questions about how to draw specific graphics that just post an image of the desired result are really not reasonable questions to ask on the site. Please post a minimal compilable document showing that you've tried to produce the image and then people will be happy to help you with any specific problems you may have.  See [minimal working example (MWE)](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) for what needs to go into such a document.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

With `pgfplots`:

```
\documentclass[border=3.141592]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.misc}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
lbl/.style = {inner sep=1pt, near end, auto},
tck/.style = {cross out, draw=#1, semithick, inner sep=4pt,
              append after command={node[circle, draw=#1, semithick, 
                                         inner sep=2pt, outer sep=1pt] at (\tikzlastnode) {}}
              }
                        ]
\begin{axis}[
    axis lines=middle,
    x label style={anchor=north east},
    domain = -7:7, samples=101,
    xmin=-9, xmax=9,  xlabel=$x$, xtick={-8,-7,...,8},  xticklabel=\empty,
    ymin=-3, ymax=12, ylabel=$y$, ytick={-2,-1,...,11}, yticklabel=\empty,
    ticklabel style={font=\footnotesize},
    extra x ticks={1},  extra x tick label=1,
    extra y ticks={1},  extra y tick label=1,
    every axis plot post/.append style={thick},
    no marks
            ]
\addplot {0.25*x^2} node[lbl]  {$0.25x^2$};
\addplot {0.6*x+5}  node[lbl,sloped] {$0.6x+5$};
\path (4,4) node[tck=blue] {}; 
\end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```